# Best practices to override/change vendor/theme files in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, themes, overriding, libraries

I am using a paid laravel theme and also using some other paid laravel libraries. I'm happy with the workflow given by them, but as per requirements i would like to make changes in those paid libraries and also would like to make change/add things in theme blade files.

I know if its not a good practice to go directly and make changes on theme files and libraries. Because, when i am going to update my libraries or theme, then my changes would go away. Can anyone recommend me a way to override these files. Also, for the sake of Laravel development what will be the good programming practices to make code updated and override other files.

Thanks

Comment: Usually running `php artisan vendor:publish` will/can publish vendor files to your `views/vendor` folder, if the theme supports it. These can be changed by you. See if there's anything on the theme's homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer this, since it depends very much on how the theme you are using loads their views which will affect your options.

If you start editing core files in the vendor folder, your changes will be wiped out on an update which is dangerous. Solving this by never updating opens door to security issues.

I would suggest speaking with the developer of the theme for their recommended way to make changes, assuming it is possible.

This could potentially include extending a class, controller etc using standard OOP principles.

It could be by extending blade templates as detailed in laravel docs.

Or it could be done by having multiple folders for views. eg laravel first checks for a view template/blade in your main app, then if it doesn't exist it falls back to the vendor folder. 
This approach can let you copy just files you change rather than all, but needs to be built into your controllers.